# Find most valuable subset of a node weighed tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization

Suppose you got a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) of positvely and negatively weighed nodes $T\hspace{-0.02 in}$.

Now I have to find the the subset ​ $M\subseteq T$ ​ such that the sum of

the weights of the nodes in $M$ is maximised, but if ​ $v \in M$ ​ then all

children of $v$ as well as their children, and so on have to be in $M$ too.

For now my algorithm is as follows:

1. calculate the depth of each node (how many nodes you have to

   traverse at maximum to reach one which doesn't have any children)
2. for all nodes $v$ of depth $n$ do the following:

   1. add up the weight of $v$ and the weights of all children and 
      grandchildren,

      ... (you get the idea) of $v$
   2. if the last step added up to a positive value then mark $v$ and

      all children of $v$ as in $M$ and don't consider them any further
   3. if the last step marked any node with the current depth then repeat

      for this depth (since the sums changed) otherwise increment n.

This works fine for some [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)s: ​ ​ ​ (Note: ​ the edges are directed downwards)
[image]

As expected all nodes except the top node are in $M$

But for othes the algorithm falls short:

[image]

The algorithm outputs that ​ $M = \emptyset$ , ​ whereas ​ $M=T$ ​ should be the case.

Is there an algorithm which solves a similar problem?

If no, how can I correct my solution? ​ Any help is highly appreciated.

PS: ​ ​ ​ I apollogize for the use of MS Paint. ​ Sorry for that.

Comment: 35. Bundeswettbewerb Informatik, Runde 2, Aufgabe 1 shame on you.

Comment: Translation: This is more or less directly a [task in the current national CS competition](http://www.bundeswettbewerb-informatik.de/fileadmin/templates/bwinf/aufgaben/bwinf35/aufgaben352.pdf) in Germany, due in April 2017.

Comment: If so, do you want me to request deletion by a moderator ?

Comment: Two cases: 1) You are participating in the contest. You already got an answer, so don't delete. Reference the answer in your solution. 2) You are not participating in the contest. Why would you delete? You've done nothing wrong. -- That said, you can always delete your own posts. (Except if you have an accepted answer, which is undoable.)

Comment: @W.Pohl Since the problem seems to be rather standard, calling shame on people without *knowing* they participate in the contest is rather shameful. Also, if the creators of the contest use a textbook problem without thinking about the power of Google, well... I find it hard to punish students for using all resources at hand, provided they give proper credit. (Of course, if too little own work remains, top grades are no longer possible.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forget the name but it's a classic minimum-cut problem. You can always consider min-cut approach when you want to choose an optimal subset.

(Edit: It's called "project selection problem".)

Think about cutting nodes into two partitions $S$, $T$ and $S$ is what we choose. Ideally we want $S$ to contain all the positive nodes and avoid any negative node. However, it's not always possible. If there exists an edge $(u,v)$, $u\in S\to v\in S$. In the min-cut model, it means we can't cut this edge, so we set $capacity(u,v)=\inf$. Next consider what we should pay if we can't assign them ideally.

Create a source $s$ and a target $t$. For each node $u$, if $w_u$ is positive, add an edge $(s,u)$ and set $capacity(s,u)=w_u$. It means we lose $w_u$ if $u\notin S$. If $w_u$ is negative, add $(u,t)$ and set $capacity(u,t)=-w_u$. It means we lose $-w_u$ if $u \in S$.

The answer is $\sum_{w_u>0} w_u-min cut(s,t)$, and $M$ is the source partition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you mean the Stoer-Wagner-Algorithm?

Comment: No, I mean the problem. I found that it's called "project selection problem", which you can even find in "max-flow min-cut theorem" wikipedia page.

Comment: FYI: This problem is part of an ongoing contest (see question). You may want to hold back your answer until after the deadline.

Comment: @Raphael Is it necessary? This problem is so classic that it can be found everywhere, for example http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/notes/24-maxflowapps.pdf  Anyway I don't know how this contest works, so I'll hold it back if you think it's necessary. How to hide the answer? Just click "delete"?

Comment: I see. There's probably no need to act in this case; it's nobody's fault if the creators of the contest were a little lazy. (They really should account for Google these days.) That said, deleting and later undeleting would be the way to do it, yes.